# Google Cloud Platform API -> "The OAuth client was deleted." Error

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm using the Google Cloud Platform API for Java (google-api-services-storage - v1beta2-rev39-1.17.0-rc).

For a couple of month It was working fine, but now I got the following error when I execute an operation.

I didn't found why the error appear. I checked if there is new version of the API but the v1beta2-rev39-1.17.0-rc is the last one.

The full stacktrace

```
2014-36-19 12:36:11.791 [qtp1800676648-24 - PUT /track_processing/process/39793ae0-f936-4ef1-9629-bd36bc5aa469] ERROR com.xxx.common.cloud_storage.GoogleCloudStorageService - Error without Json body.com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request{
  "error" : "invalid_client",
  "error_description" : "The OAuth client was deleted."}
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithoutGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:545) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:562) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeUploadInitiation(MediaHttpUploader.java:519) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:384) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:418) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460) ~[track_processing.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

This is the executed code

```
public URL upload(final InputStream mediaStream, long mediaStreamSize, final String filename) throws IOException {
        InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, mediaStream);
        if (mediaStreamSize > 0)
            mediaContent.setLength(mediaStreamSize); // Only an estimate, but allows google to optimize the upload

        StorageObject objectMetadata = new StorageObject().setName(filename)
                .setAcl(Lists.newArrayList(new ObjectAccessControl().setEntity("allUsers").setRole("READER")))
                .setContentDisposition("attachment");

        Storage.Objects.Insert insertObject = client.objects()
                                                    .insert(storageConfiguration.getBucketName(),
                                                            objectMetadata,
                                                            mediaContent);

        insertObject.getMediaHttpUploader()
                    .setProgressListener(new UploadProgressListener(mediaStreamSize > 0))
                    .setDisableGZipContent(true);

        if (mediaContent.getLength() > 0 && mediaContent.getLength() <= 2 * 1000 * 1000) {
            logger.info("{} is a small file (<2mb)", filename);
            insertObject.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(true);
        }

        return new URL(insertObject.execute().getSelfLink());
    }
```

Regards,
Ignacio

Comment: This sounds like your account might be disabled. Can you check your billing status on the cloud console?

Comment: The billing status is ok. The Json API is activated. The google documentation said "Go to the Google Developers Console.
Select a project.
In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. In the displayed list of APIs, make sure the Google Cloud Storage JSON API status is set to ON.
In the sidebar on the left, select Registered apps.
Select an application.
Expand the Browser Key or Server Key sections." but the option "registered apps"does not appears.

Comment: Could you send an email to gs-team@google.com with your project ID and bucket name?

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have been resolved outside of the normal flow for a Stack Overflow question. I'm not sure if it should be deleted or just self-answered according to what the convention is. Consider this a placemarker answer to prevent this solved issue from appearing unsolved.